UFW -- Will placing a specific IP above a CIDR allow that IP superseding the CIDR deny?
I cannot reliably get results from my testing .. But if I had said rules in this order:
zak@Web:~$sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       71.64.45.23            <- Allowing
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        ...
Anywhere                   DENY        71.64.0.0/12           <- Denying

Would the direct IP address supersede the CIDR that blocks that IP range?  In theory would not the IP in fact override the CIDR if set to position 1?
OR would the UFW read this as Allow from 71.*** THEN Deny because of the CIDR rule?
